# Extract SQL queries from text files

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

how to extract the two SQL queries using JAVA from this text file?

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  File created - 01-25-2009   
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Table PRODUCT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "PRODUCT" 
   (    "PRODUCTID" INTEGER, 
    "TYPE" VARCHAR(255), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR(10), 
    "CODE" VARCHAR(255), 
    "CLIENTS" VARCHAR(255), 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR(255), 
    "REMAININGARTICLES" VARCHAR(255), 
    "STAFF" VARCHAR(511), 
    "WAREHOUSES" VARCHAR(511), 
    "DOWN" VARCHAR(64), 
    "UP" VARCHAR(56), 
    "EXPIRY" DATE
   ) ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table PRODUCT
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "PRODUCT" MODIFY ("PRODUCTID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

This is what i have attempted so far using `spark`:

```
Dataset<String> sqlQuery=spark.read().textFile("C:/product.sql");
```

Then i try :

```
sqlQuery.toString()
```

But the latter is not returning a String, how to achieve this in a neat proper way ?

Comment: well what is it returning than? any errors or any other hints. Give as much info as possible please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlQuery is not the result you must collect it first i am not sure with java but in scala you will use it like that:

```
val arr = spark.read.textFile("C:/product.sql").collect()
```

and than join it like this:

```
val query = String.join("\n", arr: _*)
```

In java it will be something like:

```
array[] arr = spark.read().textFile("C:/product.sql").collect()
```

and than join it like this:

```
String query = String.join("\n", arr)
```

Comment: wouldn't `collectAsList` do a better job here by returning a List instead of an Array in JAVA ?

Comment: It depends on the usecase i guess which is more performant.

Comment: Also Array<String> doesnt exist in JAVA (either array[] or ArrayList ...) but thanks anyway !

Comment: yea its been years since I touched java thats why I gave you the scala equivalent so you know what has been wrong